# links under iframe /span cannot be clicked

Tags: css, iframe, html, pointer-events

I've developed a static advert ticker that sits at the bottom of the window. This is in an `<iframe>` to make it easier for other people to place the unit on their sites. Another `<span>` around the `<iframe>` keeps it fixed to the bottom of the screen. The script has a help window which is within a  tag  - within the `<iframe>` and uses the visible / hidden property to show or hide text.

Now since the code is in an `<iframe>`, the help  text would not appear on main window. To get around this, I made the `<iframe>` larger,and set it to transparent.

Visually, everything is fine. When the user clicks a button on the ticker, the help menu appears over the data in the background. However, I've just discovered that if there is a link on the main page that passes under the `<span><iframe>` section, it cannot be clicked. I've tried CSS pointer-events, but can't get that to work, (links within the `<iframe>` must also remain clickable)

Not sure which is causing the "fault", ie the `<iframe>` or the  tag around it. Is it a security thing to stop "click jacking" (??) or more to the point, is there a work around.

If push came to shove, I COULD reduce the size of the `<iframe>` and use a javascript pop-up window to display help text, but those windows show the URL and status windows, and are not exactly elegant!

Here is the code before anyone asks:
This span covers the entire screen to the height of the underlying `<iframe>` I did this so the data could be centred

```
 <span style="position:fixed;bottom:10px;display:inline;width:100%">
 <center>
 <iframe src="http://www.xxx.com/cgi-bin/ticker/run_tick.pl?s=xzy" frameborder=0 align=top width=800px height=330px marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0  scrolling=no allowtransparency=true></iframe>
 </center>
 </span>
```

Comment: Hi, I didn't rollback because the changes weren't substantial: I rolled back because the tick (`) is the correct way to set off code elements.  Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to posting on this board, so don't know the "ins and outs" of formatting the post. ALso, I didn't know it was a live person interacting, I thought it was a robot telling me of a problem, and the prompt didn't tell me a lot. So thanks for correcting me.

Comment: I clicked enter and posted rather than adding a newline, (another quirk I'll have to remember!) This morn, I've found out the problem isn't the `<iframe> as I've managed to use `<object> to embed. But problem still persists

Answer (score 1):

Set a height to the span the same as the iframe (330px)

Let me know how that goes

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but didn't help. I've now removed the `<iframe>` code, and replaced it with an `<object>` embed. The `<span>` HAS to be larger that the ticker code as it can have a picture that extends into the main page. (To get an idea of what i mean, check this out)

Comment: I've now managed to get the `<span>` to sit around 50px above the ticker for "ad6" reasons, but still any underlying link on main page that goes behind the '<span>' - above or to the sides - is not clickable. I'm hoping too that I can set up another `<span><object.` above the ticker, and hide it, to display the help text ... (which is currently within the `<iframe>' Hope this all makes sense. Oh, have also tried a tag with z-index to bring to fore, but that didn't work either

Comment: Run out of time editing comment 1. Link is:http://www.cristofayre.com/ticker (Don't click JVZoo link as I'm still in test mode with that due to PayPal problems not letting me buy my own product despite two separate accounts!)

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, what FUN I've had getting this to work!! (Twelve hours on Wed 23rd, and about three hours today)

Originally, I had an `<iframe>` that filled virtually 3/4 of screen, (so that I could display the help window to uses in a '' rather than use a modal popup. But, for security reasons, the browsers will not let you click through text that covers links underneath.

I had to literally redesign the whole layout.

Now, I have the help file in a separate `<span>` window which has its visibility set to hidden till user needs it. But that still left the ticker code at the bottom.

I had to divide that into three `<divs>` one on either side of the main ticker. But again, the ones on the side are effectively masking the page underneath, so I had to set both `<divs>` so that they used "pointer-events:none" meaning the `<div>` was not clickable, and mouse events would pass through to the code underneath. The mid section for the ticker was set to the opposite, namily "pointer-events:auto" so that the TOP window got the clicks, but not the page underneath.

Next problem: Because the ticker shows graphics that extend into the main text, that left a 1/2" area where clicks on main page couldn't be accessed. Another span was added to the code which covered the area with a transparent gif. When the user places their mouse over this graphic, a swap takes place and displays a semi transparent checkerboard. They can then read what this means in the help file.

Finally, when user's click the minimize button, the `<div>` holding the ticker code is hidden (giving accesss to all the links on the page) and ANOTHER `<div>` displays "Restore" graphic. When they click that, it gets hidden whilst the main ticker window - and the two `<divs>` on either side are made visible again.

And it was only meant to be a simple script!! (Oh, and don't check the website or my blog 'cos I won't be uploading the changes till eve of Sat 26th)